# Unable to connect to Synology NAS using my Synology domain over HTTPS on internal network, need to configure DNS Server on NAS?

Tags: networking, dns, nas, https

I just got a new Synology box today. I went through the initial setup and wanted to configure it so that I could connect over HTTPS. I went through the steps in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cwl4qmS8rtM from Synology where I added a made a Let's Encrypt certificate for aaronscloud.synology.me and had that set as the  new default DDNS cert. I changed my default https port to 50010.
When I try to go to the site I get the standard "site can't be reached" error in Chrome.
[image: site cannot be be reached]
I am able to access the DSM directly using the IP address of the box on my network
https://192.16x.xx.xx:50010/ but Chrome complains that the cert is invalid in that case because the domain on the cert (aaronscloud.synology.me) is not the same as the raw IP I am accessing it over.

I saw this video https://youtu.be/VoF-qqKwIWw?t=278 , similar to the first, but the author addresses the issue I am having and says that I am unable to access the URL I want, https://aaronscloud.synology.me:50010, because my system is trying to access my external IP address at that port. The author says I could open that port on my router, but that would be allowing for external access. ATM, I would prefer not to allow external access. I am interested in internal access only.
So it looks like I am going to have to set up some kind of DNS server on the Synology DSM like the author  suggests? I am a bit out of my depth on that one. I found this post on the Synology forums that seems like the settings should get me most of the way there https://community.synology.com/enu/forum/17/post/55530 ?
I do not know how to change the DNS on my router like the post author suggests. Is that step necessary?
Are there any other ways to accomplish this?

I looked at this answer [Redirect HTTP to HTTPS on Synology NAS](https://superuser.com/questions/1218875/redirect-http-to-https-on-synology-nas) and tried setting up the advanced section (see pic) but that did not solve it for me, still unable to access the URL. [image: synology advanced external access options]

Comment: If you don't want to access externally, why are you worried about HTTPS? I'm also a bit confused how you were able to run the letsencrypt script without opening some port externally?

Comment: For the first question, the answer would seem to be to protect data over the wire on the internal network. You could say "it is the internal network, who would be abusing your internal network?" and I would say it is possible that someone is on the network and snooping the traffic but does not have access to the DSM?

For the second question, I am a bit perplexed by that as well. My router is a Google Onhub. I have no special port openings configured.

Comment: In theory, I could connect like https://my_ip:50010 and then I would have the encryption part of the https working for me, and my still open vector would be for a MiTM attack, explained here https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/47053/does-https-encryption-work-when-there-is-invalid-or-there-is-no-certificate#:~:text=Yes%20%2C%20the%20encryption%20still%20works,the%20certificate%20that%20is%20failing.&text=It%20is%20not%20possible%20to,the%20encryption%20itself%20still%20works.
which might be the best I can do until I get figure out the DNS solution.

Comment: Right, so your `my_ip` would be the local address, right?
Yes, that would work and would be similar to using a self-signed certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your security concerns, even in the LAN, are, of course, valid.
If you already have the SSL cert and key as you claim (ideally you would quickly check under `control panel` > `Certificate` that it's not just a self-signed certificate) you could simply edit the DNS entry for which you have the cert and point it to the local address of the NAS.

For that, you don't need to modify anything in the local network since it is a public DNS server.

If you can not edit that DNS entry for which you hold the certificate you can do one of the following:

- Create a manual host entry on each client host with which you want to access the Synology NAS.
- Create a new DNS entry with some DNS provider and have that point to the local address of the NAS. This will require you to get a new certificate/key which will be difficult since your NAS is not publicly accessible. In that case, you can follow a DNS-based verification approach.

Both of these approaches will get you to a position where you have a certificate whose servername matches the name with which you try to access the NAS. In both cases, make sure to configure to actually use that certificate using the `configure` button at `control panel` > `Certificate`.